# Build is failing in VSO while implementing CI/CD for Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

The solution is building successfully in local machine but while adding it to the build step is failing. I am running the build in VS 2015 Below is the error that I am getting:

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Error MSB3271: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture, "x86", of the implementation file "C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform\1.0.0.2\build\uap10.0....\lib\uap10.0\x86\Telerik.UI.Drawing.dll" for "C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform\1.0.0.2\build\uap10.0\....\lib\uap10.0\x86\Telerik.UI.Drawing.winmd". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and implementation file, or choose a winmd file with an implementation file that has a processor architecture which matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is caused by the setting in your vs build task in VSTS build definition.

You project seems use the x64 processor architecture but you set x86 processor architecture in build definition. So please change **MSBuild Architecture** to `MSBuild x64` and queue the build again.

[image]